# how to use ellipses in highcharts in angular to deal with long names?

Tags: angularjs, highcharts, ionic-framework

i am having a high chart having email ids on x axis that are very long i have included ellipses to cut it short but the problem is it is now showing me email ids like this  :  "  `<A HREF="mailto:james.cla...  "`   i am not able to understand why it is appending anchor tag in front of the email ids , kindly help.

here is my controller code :

```
                 $scope.chart = {
                                "type": $scope.chartType,
                                "series": chartData[0],
                                "xAxis": {
                                    //labels tilted down to view properly 
                                        labels: {
                                         rotation: -20,
                                         // using ellipses in highcharts 
                                        formatter: function() {
                            return(this.value.substring(0,25) + "...");
                        }

                                    },
                                    "categories": chartData[1],
                                    "title": {
                                        "text": 'Approver name'
                                    }
                                },


                                "chart": {
                                    "plotBackgroundColor": 'transparent'
                                },
                                "yAxis": {
                                    "title": {
                                        "text": "Record count"
                                    }
                                },
                                "title": 'aging data'
                            };
                        }
```

i have only included the formatter: function to make it done .

Comment: What are the contents of `chartData[1]`?

Comment: Could you recreate your example as live demo ? Do you use highcharts-ng wrapper or native highchartS?